# Software para criar relacionamento e estrutura de DB MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, relacionamento

Estou com um projeto em mente e gostaria de mapear os dados e criar o relacionamento das tabelas, mesmo que apenas visualmente antes de desenvolver as páginas, poderiam me indicar um software (Acho que o conceito é MER) de preferência livre que me ajude a criar visualmente essas tabelas e o relacionamento entre elas?

Gostaria de algo apenas para criar os campos das tabelas e o relacionamento entre elas, nada complexo como Microsoft Visio, nada de diagramas.

Comment: Gosto dessa ferramenta: https://www.draw.io/

Comment: Complexo demais pra minha primeira experiência, gostaria de algo apenas para criar os campos da tabela e relacionar as tabelas entre si, nada tão complexo assim, obrigado pela dica, vou guardar a URL para aprender mais sobre ele. Parece o Microsoft Visio né. Valeu.

Comment: Se estiver utilizando o MySql Workbench, ele próprio possui esse tipo de funcionalidade, de gerar a diagramação do seu banco de dados

Comment: Vou baixá-lo, já utilizei para migração de banco, mas a parte de relacionamento nunca. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Usando esse draw.io que é uma ferramenta online e free, basta clicar em `file > new`.
Selecionar a aba Software e já da pra carregar um exemplo pronto, pra partir de algo já pronto.
O interessante nele é que já existe integração com diversas ferramentas para salvar os seus diagramas e fluxogramas. Tipo o GDrive e o GitHub.

Comment: Se quiser, também da pra usar o PHPMyAdmin pra gerar o diagrama..... Na verdade existem várias maneiras de se fazer.

Comment: No PHPMyAdmin: Selecione a base de dados que deseja criar a diagramação, e procure pela aba "Mais" > "Desenhador" : https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFGgy.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se sua intenção é usar o MySQL, o [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) pode ser uma boa alternativa. É gratuito (licença GPL) e tem bons recursos para você criar o modelo lógico e exportar como modelo físico ou vice-versa. Possui versões para Windows, Linux e OS X.
Depois de instalar, clique em File > New Model > Add Diagram.

Comment: Pois bem, Workbench pelas dicas e pelo que li é realmente o que preciso, obrigado.